# Why won't CSS for hr tag show up in React code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using this code to create a border in my React code:

```html
<hr className="borderLine" />
```

however, when styling it with CSS, I am use this code:

```css
.divider {
    margin: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white; /* Adjust the color and style as needed */
  }
```

This issue is that when I use `.borderLine` for the CSS, it doesn't show up. The `hr` line only shows up on the page using `.divider`, but no class is named `.divider`.

I have tried renaming all the `className`'s, but it did not make a difference, it just didn't show up unless I used `.divider`. I even cleared my cache.

Comment: You might need to check whether your css file were inserted correctly.

Comment: Can you try to replicate the issue by creating sandbox?

Comment: Did you read @J L's answer? Had the same feeling it could be that. You said "not showing up" - please check via right-click and inspect element in console. CSS inspector will show you better whats going on.

Answer (score 2):

### *UPDATE* - Added a working code sandbox for you to practice with [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/css-example-66qy6w?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900063b6k7jlrjkmk%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900023b6k81hsg81q%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900033b6khi9t9yuq%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900053b6kuhi89rk5%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqsd2dm900023b6k81hsg81q%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900013b6kvcsh02w4%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252Findex.html%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900023b6k81hsg81q%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900013b6kvcsh02w4%2522%257D%252C%2522clqsd2dm900053b6kuhi89rk5%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900043b6kw8jlm7ka%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900053b6kuhi89rk5%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900043b6kw8jlm7ka%2522%257D%252C%2522clqsd2dm900033b6khi9t9yuq%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900033b6khi9t9yuq%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

steps for CSS:

1. Create the CSS file such as 'styles.css'
2. Import the CSS file at the top of the component you want to use it in
3. Make sure the name in the CSS file is the same as the className you want to use it on. (for example if css is `.borderLiine{}` then classname should be `className='borderLine'`
4. If you 'can't see' the hr when borderLine class is applied, make sure your color and background color contrast each other (ex. light grey, offwhite etc can be very difficult to see on white backgrounds)

---

### Quick Fix

If you want the least amount of code edits/work, keep your CSS the same and change your hr to this:

```
<hr className='divider' />
```

That will make the divider CSS apply to the hr.

### Whats Happening (issue explained) & Other Solutions

If you want to understand more or keep borderLine as a class name:

*The issue is*: your CSS code is trying to style a className called 'divider' by declaring `.divider{}`(period means className) but the hr className you have is called 'borderLine' so nothing happens.

The two names must be the same if you want CSS to take effect (and the **CSS file must be imported**)

It looks like you want to use borderLine instead of divider as a className, to do this you just need to change your CSS declaration or add a borderLine declaration like below.

Copy and paste this to replace the .divider css and it should work:

```
/*CSS FILE:(ex. styles.css)*/

.borderLine {
        margin: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid white; /* Adjust the color and style as needed */
      }
```

### Example Usage

of borderLine [(see working example in codesandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/css-example-66qy6w?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900063b6k7jlrjkmk%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900023b6k81hsg81q%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900033b6khi9t9yuq%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900053b6kuhi89rk5%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqsd2dm900023b6k81hsg81q%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900013b6kvcsh02w4%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252Findex.html%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900023b6k81hsg81q%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900013b6kvcsh02w4%2522%257D%252C%2522clqsd2dm900053b6kuhi89rk5%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900043b6kw8jlm7ka%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900053b6kuhi89rk5%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900043b6kw8jlm7ka%2522%257D%252C%2522clqsd2dm900033b6khi9t9yuq%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900033b6khi9t9yuq%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D):

```
import './styles.css';
const Example = () = > {
  //example usage
  return <hr className='borderLine' />
}
```

**Also, ensure you are importing the css file wherever you try to use it. (ex import `'./styles.css'`)**

**OR**

If you want inline styles approach which always works: (generally not ideal unless unique styling is needed, but it will always work)

```
<hr style={{ 
   margin: "2rem", 
   width: "100%", 
   color: "white", 
   border: "1px solid white" 
}}/>
```

I highly suggest [checking out this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/css-example-66qy6w?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900063b6k7jlrjkmk%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900023b6k81hsg81q%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900033b6khi9t9yuq%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900053b6kuhi89rk5%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqsd2dm900023b6k81hsg81q%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900013b6kvcsh02w4%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252Findex.html%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900023b6k81hsg81q%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900013b6kvcsh02w4%2522%257D%252C%2522clqsd2dm900053b6kuhi89rk5%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900043b6kw8jlm7ka%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900053b6kuhi89rk5%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900043b6kw8jlm7ka%2522%257D%252C%2522clqsd2dm900033b6khi9t9yuq%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900033b6khi9t9yuq%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) **and comparing it with your code** as it successfully styles and displays an hr tag with your borderLine class!

### [Click here for CodeSanbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/css-example-66qy6w?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900063b6k7jlrjkmk%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900023b6k81hsg81q%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900033b6khi9t9yuq%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900053b6kuhi89rk5%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqsd2dm900023b6k81hsg81q%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900013b6kvcsh02w4%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252Findex.html%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900023b6k81hsg81q%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900013b6kvcsh02w4%2522%257D%252C%2522clqsd2dm900053b6kuhi89rk5%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900043b6kw8jlm7ka%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900053b6kuhi89rk5%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900043b6kw8jlm7ka%2522%257D%252C%2522clqsd2dm900033b6khi9t9yuq%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqsd2dm900033b6khi9t9yuq%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: I tried doing that but the CSS only shows up with .divider name in the CSS.

Comment: that's fine, if the css cannot be changed or if you just want to use .divider then in your <hr> classname use "divider" like the last example

Comment: also whatever css file you are using make sure you import it to where you are trying to use it. for example if its called styles.css make sure at the top of the file you import it

Comment: i added more examples including how to inline style the same CSS. If you're still having issues it would be very helpful if I could see the full code either on here(edit answer and add full code),or github, or codesandbox (all are free!)

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your CSS ClassName .divider To .borderLine
2. Make Sure You Are Imported CSS correctly.
   For Ex. `import "./style.css";`

Comment: It only works if the CSS has .divider.

Answer (score 0):

> This issue is that when I use .borderLine for the CSS, it doesn't show
> up.

- This is because `border: 1px solid white;` border line colour is white and I assume that the background colour is also white

> The hr line only shows up on the page using .divider, but no class is
> named .divider.

- The target class name is `borderLine` from `<hr className="borderLine" />`. If you change the selector name `.borderLine` -> `.divider` in CSS, the hr line will appear since none of styling will be applied to the `hr` element.

Try by changing the colour of border in css to see it starts appearing (**if border colour and background are identical, the hr line is technically there, but you cannot see it** )

```
    <hr className="borderLine" />
```

```
.borderLine {
    margin: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid red; /* Adjust the colour */
  }
```